# npm install, but can't run

Tags: command-line-interface, npm

I'm a newbie to Node, but I've been trying to install some npm modules and after what seems like a successful install, I can't run the new app.  I must have some basic config error, like a missing location in my PATH...

For example, running:

```
npm install -g karma
```

I get:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
... (many, many GETs......)

> ws@0.4.25 install /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node: Finished
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node: Finished
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/karma -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/karma/bin/karma

> karma@0.8.3 install /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/karma
> node install-log4js.js

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/log4js/0.6.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/log4js/0.6.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.1.15
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/dequeue/1.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/dequeue/1.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.1.15
log4js@0.6.2 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/log4js
├── dequeue@1.0.3
└── async@0.1.15
karma@0.8.3 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/karma
├── pause@0.0.1
├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── xmlbuilder@0.4.2
├── colors@0.6.0-1
├── chokidar@0.6.2
├── growly@1.1.1
├── mime@1.2.9
├── q@0.9.2
├── coffee-script@1.6.2
├── lodash@1.1.1
├── rimraf@2.1.4 (graceful-fs@1.2.0)
├── optimist@0.3.5 (wordwrap@0.0.2)
├── minimatch@0.2.11 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.3.0)
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.0, graceful-fs@1.2.0)
├── LiveScript@1.0.1 (prelude-ls@0.6.0)
├── log4js@0.6.2 (dequeue@1.0.3, async@0.1.15)
├── http-proxy@0.10.0 (pkginfo@0.2.3, utile@0.1.7)
├── istanbul@0.1.22 (abbrev@1.0.4, which@1.0.5, fileset@0.1.5, nopt@2.0.0, wordwrap@0.0.2, async@0.1.22, mkdirp@0.3.5, esprima@0.9.9, handlebars@1.0.10, escodegen@0.0.20)
└── socket.io@0.9.14 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.io-client@0.9.11)
```

But when I then try to run:

```
➤ karma start
fish: Unknown command 'karma'
```

Of course, if I run it by directly addressing the entire path to karma, it works fine:

```
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/karma/bin/karma start

 Starting Testacular Server (http://vojtajina.github.com/testacular)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [karma]: Karma server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 26.0 (Mac)]: Connected on socket id sNhp2l8FW6zQ0iQsiRgR
Chrome 26.0 (Mac): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.108 secs / 0.004 secs)
```

When I npm install something, isn't a symlink created somewhere?

```
➤ which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm

➤ npm --version
1.2.14
```

Comment: A symlink is created to the javascript library so that other javascript programs can use it. That has nothing to do with what happens to binaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it by adding /usr/local/share/npm/bin to my path.  (via editing my .bashrc file)

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this Karma setup page](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/intro/installation.html).

Run:

```
npm install karma-cli -g
```

You should be able to run `karma start` now.